# Flutter FutureBuilder gives error The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

Using **Flutter 2.8.1**

*FutureBuilder* is giving an error on accessing data by index

```dart
body: FutureBuilder<List<RecordModel>> (
        future: DatabaseProvider.instance.records(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                itemBuilder: (itemBuilder, i) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[i].phoneNumber),
                  );
                }
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('Oops...'),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      )
```

Which gives the following error

```
The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
```

on line

```
title: Text(snapshot.data[i].phoneNumber),
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can just use `!` to solve this since you're already checking `snapshot.hasData`

```
return ListTile(
       title: Text(snapshot.data![i].phoneNumber),
);
```

But in general you have to store the `snapshot.data` in a local variable and check if it's null or not. Dart can only promote local variables, not getters. So even if you check `snapshot.hasData` or `snapshot.data != null` is not enough and dart can't promote the getters. The following is from [documentation](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#working-with-nullable-fields):

> Flow-based type promotion does not apply to fields because the static
> analysis cannot prove that the field’s value doesn’t change between
> the point that you check for null and the point that you use it.
> (Consider that in pathological cases, the field itself could be
> overridden by a getter in a subclass that returns null the second time
> it is called.)

```
body: FutureBuilder<List<RecordModel>>(
        future: DatabaseProvider.instance.records(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final data = snapshot.data;
          if (data != null) {

            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                itemBuilder: (itemBuilder, i) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(data[i].phoneNumber),
                  );
                });
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('Oops...'),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
```